# How to understand this built in function in JavaScript 'Math.floor(Math.random() *6)+1'?

Tags: javascript

If I use this code:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() *6)
```

this will give me a random number from 1 to 5, am I correct?

Would it be the same to code this:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() *6)+1
```

as this?

```
Math.floor(Math.random() *7)
```

because they will both give me a number between 1 to 6?

Just watching a tutorial, he hasn't explained this function and I'm curious if he could have used the second example instead of the first one.

Comment: Start understanding that `Math.random()` returns a float between `0` (inclusive) and `1` (not inclusive). So `Math.random() * 6` will return a **float number** in the range `[0,6)` and then `Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)` an **integer number** in the range `[0,5]`.

Comment: Questions like this are often best answered by running some experiments. Just console.log each expression a large number of times. What do you observe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they will not be the same `Math.floor(Math.random() *6)+1` is random value between `1-6`(6 is max value)
. The minimum value of this one is always `1` as we are adding `1` in the end.

`Math.floor(Math.random() *7)` is random value between `0-7`

Comment: @Eduard Is there any specific reason that you unaccepted the other answer and accepted mine.

Answer (score 2):

`Math.random()` will return a number from 0(inclusive) - 1(exclusive), which is to say the number can go as low as zero but never quite hit 1.  We multiply that by 6 so now it goes from 0 to almost 6. Then we `.floor` it which means we now have an integer from 0-5.  Adding 1 brings that integer to the range 1-6 (including both endpoints).

`Math.floor(Math.random() *7)` would get the random number from 0 to 1, then multiply by 7 to make it 0 to almost 7, then floor would be 0-6.  So close, but not quite.

Docs:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Answer (score 1):

`Math.random()` gives you a pseudorandom number from between 0 and 1.

Multiply it by 6, you get the range of 0 to 6. Multiply it by 7, you get 0-7. Add 1, and both ends move up by 1.

`Math.floor()` is "the largest integer no bigger than...". Simply, rounds down.

So, putting it all together, `Math.floor(Math.random() *6)` is: take some pseudorandom number from somewhere between 0 and 6, and round it down - it'll be one of `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` (you won't get 6, because with Math.random() you'll never get exactly 1).

Similarly, `Math.floor(Math.random() *6)+1` is the above plus 1 (so, a toss of the regular cubic die). And `Math.floor(Math.random() *7)` means some number from `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.